# Completely hide files on Linux

Tags: linux, ls

i was wondering if there's a way to prevent a `ls -a` command to display certain files to certain `user`/`group`
The criteria could be:
if the file is hidden and the `user`/`group` has no read access, then don't even show it.
or maybe ..
if the file has a certain `extended_attribute` and the `user`/`group` has no read access, then don't even show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends if you are using SELinux and/or Extended Attributes.

It will depend on what version and which distribution of linux you are using.  Fedora, for example, has SELinux enabled.  With extended attributes, on the other hand, you have to load them separately.

With standard unix permissions, `ls -a` will display all files in a folder.  This does not hide the filename from users who have read access rights to that folder.  You can deny read rights to a file by limiting read rights to a specific user, or denying read access to the folder's named group.

If you want to hide files from certain users or groups of users, you need to put them into a directory (folder) that they do not have 'read' access to.

With Extended Attributes, and ACL's you may be able to achieve what you looking to do, but it is not as standard.

Comment: And if you want to make files *inaccessible* to certain users or groups of users, you need to put them in a directory that those users do not have *execute* permission to. On directories, "read" means "enumerate contents of", and "execute" means "descend into", the directory.